# Redirect entire url including # in IIS 6

Tags: iis, iis-6, redirect

How can I redirect

```
http://myserver.com/MyApp/#/Welcome?page=2
```

to

```
https://myserver.com/MyApp/#/Welcome?page=2
```

in IIS 6?

I tried using `https://myserver.com$S` but it leaves out the `#` and anything after it.  Same with any of the other [redirect variables](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx?mfr=true).

(In case you're wondering, the # is used to enable deep linking in a Silverlight app.)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the below URL:

http://www.jppinto.com/2009/01/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis-6/

Answer (score 1):

The server never sees the anchor. The processing for those is done completely client-side.